# How to Read and Write from/to the same XML file in Visual Basic/C# using Data Set?

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, dataset

I have a list which can contain whatever objects(for example, in the instance I copied below, the list can have one "order" or ten "orders"). I used data contract and I get this output (There is Only one order/One object in the OrderList):

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
 -<frmStartup.SerializeClass xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- 
instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BAKFAA">
 -<Orderlist>
    -<Order>
       <Number>1</Number>
       <OrderDistance>150</OrderDistance>
       -<OffsetX xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Arrays">
          <a:double>59.00</a:double>
          <a:double>70.80</a:double>
        </OffsetX>
       -<OffsetY xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003">
          <a:double>43</a:double>
          <a:double>54</a:double>
        </OffsetY>
        <deflection>
          <a:double>76</a:double>
          <a:double>23</a:double>
        </deflection>
        <Comment> 2014 10 08 15 19 50</Comment>
     </Order>
  </Orderlist>
</frmStartup.SerializeClass>
```

Based on my understanding of Data Contract, It returns the data structure that has been used in the program.

I am requested to create the new format of the XML output (which is different than what Data Contract creates). In the new assignment, I am asked to create a tentative structure that is very different than what Data Contract provide. I am working on an integration project which means 3 different programs can read and write on the same file. Because of that, in the output file, there are other variables that even are not available in the current program. The output file  needs to be similar to this (Compare it with the above output that Data Contract creates):

```
  <Country>
    <Company>
       <CompanyName>aa</CompanyName>
          <branch>
              <branchName>bb</branchName>
                <OrderList>
                   <order>
                     <comment>32 53 65 76 854</comment>
                     <OrderDistance>532</OrderDistance>
                       <deflection>
                         <offsetX>0</offsetX>
                         <offsetY>0</offsetY>
                         <deflValue>10.45</deflValue>
                       </deflection>
                       <deflection>
                         <offsetX>0</offsetX>
                         <offsetY>0</offsetY>
                         <deflValue>10.45</deflValue>
                       </deflection>
                  </order>
                    <order>
                 <comment>332 23 45 56 54</comment>
                 <OrderDistance>122</OrderDistance>
                   <deflection>
                     <offsetX>5</offsetX>
                     <offsetY>3</offsetY>
                     <deflValue>10.45</deflValue>
                   </deflection>
                   <deflection>
                     <offsetX>0</offsetX>
                     <offsetY>0</offsetY>
                     <deflValue>10.45</deflValue>
                   </deflection>
              </order>
             </OrderList>
          </branch> 
     </Company>
  </Country>
```

I tried to use a dataset and copy the values into different tables and finally create XML out of DataSet. The advantage of using DataSet is that I can copy the XML input file in it and only change the values that are changed during the program process and save those changes in the output file along with those variables that have not been changed. It seems a very difficult approach to me and I have to keep track of primary keys and foreign keys(Please correct me if I am wrong). Please help me to find a better solution to this problem.

Comment: [Paste XML as Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/generating-data-type-classes-from-xml)

Comment: Thank you for making a comment, but I didn't get what this page want to say. It seems irrelevant to my question to me. I want to get XML output which has different levels of tags from different structures exist in different classes of the software. Could you make a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem myself.

I uploaded a desired template of the output with only one object as follow in the root of the program:

```
 <Country>
    <Company>
       <CompanyName>aa</CompanyName>
          <branch>
              <branchName>bb</branchName>
                <OrderList>
                   <order>
                     <comment>32 53 65 76 854</comment>
                     <OrderDistance>532</OrderDistance>
                       <deflection>
                         <offsetX>0</offsetX>
                         <offsetY>0</offsetY>
                         <deflValue>10.45</deflValue>
                       </deflection>
                       <deflection>
                         <offsetX>0</offsetX>
                         <offsetY>0</offsetY>
                         <deflValue>10.45</deflValue>
                       </deflection>
                  </order>
             </OrderList>
          </branch> 
     </Company>
  </Country>
```

Then I read the uploaded XML file to a dataset and then from the program I counted the number of objects that program created and looped through them to copy the values I wanted in the tables of the dataset. I added new rows to add require information (columns). For keeping track of the relationships between the tables, I used primary keys and foreign keys as follow:

```
Public Shared XMLDom As DataSet = New DataSet
XMLDom.ReadXml("../../XMLOutput_template.xml")
 For k = 0 To orderlistInXMl.Count - 1

         XMLDom.Tables("order").Rows.Add()

         XMLDom.Tables("order").Rows(k).Item("orderNumber") = 
         orderlistInXMl.Item(k).DropNumber
         XMLDom.Tables("order").Rows(k).Item("OrderDistance") = 
         basinlistInXMl.Item(k).Distance

         XMLDom.Tables("order").Rows(k).Item("orderlist_id") = 
         XMLDom.Tables("orderlist").Rows(0).Item("orderlist_id")
```

The keys to the solution of this problem were to upload a template of the desired solution in the root of the program. In this way, I didn't have to create tables relationships and second was the last command in the codes above that checks the foreign keys of the child with the primary keys of parents in the tables.